# OnActionExpandListener in menuitem not working. How to fix it?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, searchview

I am developing an Android application which works from API Level 14.

I have an item in my menu file

```
  <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
         android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

I want to know the expansion  and collapse of this search view,i  tried this code but it is not working

```
    @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_search, menu);
            MenuItem mSearchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);

            mSearchItem.setOnActionExpandListener( new OnActionExpandListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onMenuItemActionExpand", 1)
                     .show();
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onMenuItemActionExpand", 1)
                     .show();
                    return true;

                }
            });
    }

}
```

Why am i not getting the Toasts?

I also tried code form [Handling collapsible action views](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionViewCollapsing), it is also not working! Why these things are not working?

**EDIT**

I can get it work using

```
mSearchView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right,
                    int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight,
                    int oldBottom) {

                SearchView searchView = (SearchView) v;
                if (searchView.isIconified()) {
                       }
                       else{
                        }
           }
   });
```

But it is very slow!

Comment: After 2 Hours i find it out i needed to use  android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"

Comment: I just posted your comment as answer so others can see it.

Answer (score 6):

Was having similar issue the solution is ( commented by the asker, I am just positing so it can get more emphasis):

add `android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"` to your menu item.

```
 <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:queryHint = "@string/search_hint"/>
```

Comment: this disables the expanding , collapsing function for me and shows only static search icon button! any suggestions?

Comment: @Learner_Programmer this is the fix : `return true` instead of `false` in the `onMenuItemActionExpand`

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onMenuItemActionExpand", 1).show();
```

it is recommended to either use `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` or `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` instead of your "1".

**example:**

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onMenuItemActionExpand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, 1 is the constant value for    Toast.LENGTH_LONG see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#LENGTH_LONG Any way i put it for testing only..

Comment: i don't use digits. eclipse just keeps showing a warning then. I also checked your main problem, but two projects on github use it exactly like you do. Have you tried debugging or some logcat-outputs to limit the sources of evil?

Comment: I used logcat-outputs  too but no success. Can you please provide the link to the github project?

Comment: not on github though, but here is the link! http://code.google.com/p/frank-gairal-android/source/browse/trunk/src/com/dro/frank/gairal/activity/AbstractActivity.java?spec=svn5&r=5#404

Comment: It is using ActionBarSherlock i dont need ActionBarSherlock